# what does closure do in the code below?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
//case 1
setInterval(function(){someFunc()},5000);
var someFunc=function (){
    alert('in the someFunc');
}
//case 2
setInterval(someFunc,5000);
var someFunc=function (){
    alert('in the someFunc');
}
```

what is the difference between the two cases?In the compilation phase,both case 1 and case 2 the someFunc is undefined and in execution phase the someFunc is not changed where the setInterval function be called,why case 1 can success ?the only difference between case 1 and case 2 is the closure in case 1 .what does the closure do in case 1?

Answer (score 1):

Through the `var` declaration, the variable is "hoisted". Meaning, it exists in the scope as a name, even before anything has been assigned to it. Hence it can be "closed over". At the time the interval is executing, the value of `someFunc` is a function, hence it can be called.

In the second case `someFunc` still contains the value `undefined` at the time you're passing it into `setInterval`. Since `undefined` is not a function, it cannot be used as a callback at the time you want to set the interval.

"Hoisting" explained in a nutshell:

```
var foo = 'bar';
function () {
    console.log(foo); // undefined
    var foo = 'baz';
}
```

The inner `var foo` is *shadowing* the outer `var foo`, even before anything has been assigned to it. It already exists in the scope, to the extent that it shadows other variables of the same name.

Comment: why case 2 someFunc can not "closured over"?i don't get it!

Comment: Because in your second case you don't have a closure. You need to pass a *callback function* to `setInterval`. In the first case, you're passing an anonymous function; which happens to close over `someFunc`. In the second case, you're simply trying to pass `undefined` as a callback to `setInterval`. You didn't close anything over because you didn't write any function.

Comment: it means that only closure can access to the outer scope till window,right?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: under common circumstance is only search the context where it is been created, the context is within a function,right?

Comment: Inside a function you have access to all variables which are in scope at the point where the function is being defined. That's the "surrounding" scope, the surrounding scope around that, the surrounding scope around that etc. all the way up to the top level scope. If the function is executed asynchronously, as it is in your case, then those variables are *still* all accessible; in this case it's said that they're "closed over".

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are defining a function that will look for someFunc when it is executed, in that case 5 seconds later.

In the second example you are telling to setInterval that in that moment someFunc exists but that is not the case.

Comment: Well, `someFunc` *exists*, but its value is not a function.

Comment: I should say exists as a function :D

Comment: It's really about distinguishing *variables* from their *values*. The *variable* exists, but the value it holds is not a function. The variables *never* "exists as a function"; the variable exists or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in the second case because you are handing in a reference to a function which is, at this point, `undefined`. If you were to reorder the function as such:

```
var someFunc=function (){
    alert('in the someFunc');
}
setInterval(someFunc,5000);
```

Then `someFunc` would be defined and `setInterval` could use that value.

The first method works because the closure will, at the time of execution (which is in 5 seconds) close over ("composite" the context with it's own, you could say, or "inherit" that context) the context the closure was defined in. Thus, `someFunc` is defined at this time.

Comment: That sounds as if the closing over the parent scope would happen at the execution time, not at the creation time.

Comment: Yep, that's what happens here... If it even matters, because the context might just be linked as a whole, then it wouldn't matter.

Comment: But it *does* happen at the creation time.

Comment: @Bergi then I suppose the context just gets closed over as a whole, as a pointer, at creation time... Doesn't defeat my logic, afaik